# Differentiable and homogeneous.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

I am kinda stuck here. How do i start the proof?

Comment: differentitiate $f(tx)=t^{\alpha}f(x)$ with respect to $t$ and set $t=1$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one piece of puzzle:

Start with ${f((t+h)x)-f(tx)}\over{hx}$ and simplify.

Here is another:

Also check that ${f(tx+th)-f(tx)} \over {th}$, take limit and simplify to get $f'(tx)=t^{\alpha-1} f'(x)$.

compare the two results and see if that gives the final answer.